# Is it possible to tree-shake module imports in live-served storybook?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, storybook, tree-shaking

I use Storybook with [**CRA preset**](https://github.com/storybookjs/presets/tree/master/packages/preset-create-react-app) in my project and run Storybook locally. I would like to use namespace imports in my storybook for better developer experience:

```
// this is more convenient
import { ArrowForward, Star } from '@material-ui/icons';

// than this
import ArrowForward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowForward'
import Star from '@material-ui/icons/Star'
```

It seems to be tree-shaking correctly during the build process - both approaches yield the same bundle size.

However when running storybook locally via `yarn storybook`, importing from the aggregate namespace:

```
import { ArrowForward, Star } from '@material-ui/icons'
```

results in approximately 20 seconds longer build time.

I tried using both tree-shaking plugins from [**material ui guide**](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2) with the suggested config inside `projectRoot/.storybook.babelrc.js`, but with no luck.

It sure processes the `.babelrc.js`, since invalid syntax there breaks the build. However it still loads all the icons.

Is it possible to get it working within a CRA?

Comment: There seems to be a section about how to get it to work with CRA in that same link

Comment: As far as I understand it, that's for when you want to tree-shake within CRA build, not Storybook. It says "If you are using Create React App, you will need to use a couple of projects that let you use .babelrc configuration, without ejecting.". But Storybook seems to solve that problem for me with its custom .babelrc.js file.

Comment: Also, I don't see how modifying the`yarn start` script to use the react-app-rewired would influence the result of running `yarn storybook`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to combine guide from [Material-UI: Minimizing Bundle Size](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2) and [Storybook: Configure Babel](https://storybook.js.org/docs/riot/configure/babel#custom-configuration).

---

After install babel-plugin-import.

`yarn add -D babel-plugin-import`

On the `.storybook/main.js` you'll have to add these 2 babel plugin config into storybook babel plugin.

```js
module.exports = {
  babel: async (options) => {
    options.plugins.push([
      'babel-plugin-import',
      {
        libraryName: '@material-ui/core',
        libraryDirectory: '',
        camel2DashComponentName: false,
      },
      'core',
    ]);
    options.plugins.push([
      'babel-plugin-import',
      {
        libraryName: '@material-ui/icons',
        libraryDirectory: '',
        camel2DashComponentName: false,
      },
      'icons',
    ]);

    return options;
  },
};
```

---

After it done after trying to run storybook, you might encounter error like this.

`Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/makeStyles' in '/your/project'`

You will have to change

`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';`

into

`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`